# Eliminating Duplicate base on criterias using R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to clean up data frame using dplyr , For each element in a specific column, keep only one element of the other columns and eliminating all the duplicates

In this case, for each part number  ( Part_No) ,  I want to retain all unique values  fpr all Operation (Op) , but eliminating duplicates.

```
structure(list(Order = c("100003378", "100003378", "100003378", 
"100003378", "100003378", "100003378", "100003378", "100003378", 
"100016566", "100016566", "100016566", "100016566", "100016566", 
"100016566", "100016566"), Op = c(1016, 1017, 1018, 1019, 1020, 
1400, 1500, 9997, 1800, 1850, 1950, 2100, 2105, 2110, 2115), 
    `Op Desc` = c("SOLDER REWORK IAW 200358984", "PP&C REWORK IAW 200358984", 
    "INSPECT IAW 200358984", "QNOTE REVIEW IAW 200358984", "WI 1000   Program FPGA / Test CCA", 
    "WI 1400   Vacuum Bake", "WI 1500   Quality Inspection", 
    "PP&C Material Movement / Go To Stock", "WI1800Test,TempTest,Tune Puck by Sanding", 
    "WI 1850   Bond SAT Wires, As Required", "WI 1950  QC Inspect SAT Wires, As Req'd", 
    "WI 2100   Test, As Required", "ASSEMBLY REWORK IAW 200377998", 
    "PP&C REWORK IAW 200377998", "BOND REWORK IAW 200377998"), 
    Part_No = c("2355805G1", "2355805G1", "2355805G1", "2355805G1", 
    "2355805G1", "2355805G1", "2355805G1", "2355805G1", "2353604G1", 
    "2353604G1", "2353604G1", "2353604G1", "2353604G1", "2353604G1", 
    "2353604G1"), WBS = c("G-CUST-01", "G-CUST-01", "G-CUST-01", 
    "G-CUST-01", "G-CUST-01", "G-CUST-01", "G-CUST-01", "G-CUST-01", 
    "G-CUST-01", "G-CUST-01", "G-CUST-01", "G-CUST-01", "G-CUST-01", 
    "G-CUST-01", "G-CUST-01"), `Work Cntr` = c("CHRP0000", "CHRP0000", 
    "CHRI0000", "CHRP0000", "26502122", "26303014", "26601012", 
    "26801702", "26502132", "26203022", "26601012", "26502132", 
    "CHRP0000", "CHRP0000", "CHRP0000"), `Actual Start` = structure(c(1576610787.297, 
    1578489110.297, 1578493446.18, 1578600321, 1578617121.747, 
    1578943396.57, 1580227782.307, 1580417882.567, 1548185774.11, 
    1580986391.243, 1580986432.387, 1580986503.387, 1585258772.203, 
    1585647392.113, 1585696342.92), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), `Actual Comp` = structure(c(1578443159.437, 1578489164.8, 
    1578494073.52, 1578600334.077, 1578618039.147, 1579611732.62, 
    1580413592.273, 1580417887.177, 1580986384.79, 1580986425.4, 
    1580986495.387, 1580986510.713, 1585592063.483, 1585647532.507, 
    1585696944.333), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    )), Operation_Span = structure(c(21.2080108796308, 0.000630821759502093, 
    0.00726087962863622, 0.000151354165540801, 0.0106180555566593, 
    7.73537094907352, 2.15057831018611, 5.33564830267871e-05, 
    379.636697685186, 0.000395335648898725, 0.000729166666666667, 
    8.47916663796813e-05, 3.85753796296263, 0.00162493055617368, 
    0.00696079860958788), class = "difftime", units = "days"), 
    Cum_Total_Span = c(21.2080108796308, 21.7404803587965, 21.7972942476858, 
    23.0271618055552, 23.2320815972239, 34.7331634606476, 44.0139464814823, 
    44.0636560185198, 379.636697685186, 379.637167708336, 379.637977743058, 
    379.638155127317, 432.943164039354, 433.585166631945, 434.157062766204
    )), row.names = c(NA, -15L), groups = structure(list(Order = c("100003378", 
"100016566"), Part_No = c("2355805G1", "2353604G1"), .rows = structure(list(
    1:8, 9:15), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1:2, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Another wat to describe what I am looking for. I need to see all the operation (op)  per part number (Part_No) ,  eliminating the rest of the rows that I dont need.

Comment: What would be your expected output for the data shared? Do you want to keep only 1 row for each `Order` and `Part_No` ? `df %>% distinct(Order, Part_No, .keep_all = TRUE)`

Comment: I dont want to see Orders anymore. I just want to see a list of all Op and Op_Description for each part number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the unique values of `Op` and `Op Desc` for each `Part_No` using `distinct`. Also as your data is grouped you may need to `ungroup` first.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% ungroup %>% distinct(Part_No, Op, `Op Desc`)


#      Op `Op Desc`                                Part_No  
#   <dbl> <chr>                                    <chr>    
# 1  1016 SOLDER REWORK IAW 200358984              2355805G1
# 2  1017 PP&C REWORK IAW 200358984                2355805G1
# 3  1018 INSPECT IAW 200358984                    2355805G1
# 4  1019 QNOTE REVIEW IAW 200358984               2355805G1
# 5  1020 WI 1000   Program FPGA / Test CCA        2355805G1
# 6  1400 WI 1400   Vacuum Bake                    2355805G1
# 7  1500 WI 1500   Quality Inspection             2355805G1
# 8  9997 PP&C Material Movement / Go To Stock     2355805G1
# 9  1800 WI1800Test,TempTest,Tune Puck by Sanding 2353604G1
#10  1850 WI 1850   Bond SAT Wires, As Required    2353604G1
#11  1950 WI 1950  QC Inspect SAT Wires, As Req'd  2353604G1
#12  2100 WI 2100   Test, As Required              2353604G1
#13  2105 ASSEMBLY REWORK IAW 200377998            2353604G1
#14  2110 PP&C REWORK IAW 200377998                2353604G1
#15  2115 BOND REWORK IAW 200377998                2353604G1
```

Comment: It works. Thanks.  One more question. Is there a way to filter this result so I can see Op Description where the first two characters are WI?

Comment: Yes, you can add to the above answer `%>% filter(grepl('^WI', \`Op Desc\`))`